# Tensor Cross Product

Tags: vectors, tensor-products

I have solved a cross product of $(a \times b  )\cdot (c \times d) $

I expressed the above equation in this way :

$$\epsilon_{ijk} a_jb_k \epsilon_{min} c_m d_n$$ And by using the kronecker delta function i got this result = $$(a \cdot c ) (b \times d) - (a \cdot d )( (b \times c)  $$

My problem is that i'm solving another equation which is:

$(a \times b  )\times (c \times d) $ which should be equal to $$a \cdot (b \times d) c  - a \cdot (b \times c) d $$ but i'm messing with the  tensor equations because i see another cross product.  Can you help me how to deal with the multiple cross product by levi_civita tensor  analysis?

Comment: Your writing in the second expression $a \cdot (b \times d) c  - a \cdot (b \times c) d$ is ambiguous. Is it $(a \cdot (b \times d)) c  - (a \cdot (b \times c)) d$ ?

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 1):

Your first identity doesn't seem to be right, since you are performing the scalar product of two vectors and the result should be a scalar (it seems to be just a typo, though). Anyway I will do it once again, but this time making use of the covariant-contravariant convention for indices.

I'll use parenthes to make the process easier to follow, but they do not have any meaning since the tensor product is associative.
$$\begin{align}
(a\times b) \cdot (c\times d)
&= g_{ij}({\epsilon_{mn}}^{i}a^{m}b^{n})({\epsilon_{pq}}^{j}c^{p}d^{q})\\
&=(\epsilon^{mni}a_{m}b_{n})(\epsilon_{pqi}c^{p}d^{q})\\
&=\delta^{mni}_{pqi}(a_{m}b_{n})(c^{p}d^{q})\\
&=\delta^{mn}_{pq}(a_{m}b_{n})(c^{p}d^{q})\\
&=2(a_{[p}b_{q]})(c^{p}d^{q})\\
&= (a_pc^p)(b_qd^q) - (c^pb_p)(a_qd^q)\\
&= (a \cdot c)(b \cdot d) - (c \cdot b)(a \cdot d)\\
\end{align}$$

As you can see, the result is indeed a scalar.

The second one is
$$\begin{align}
[(a\times b) \times (c\times d)]^k
&= {\epsilon_{ij}}^{k}({\epsilon_{mn}}^{i}a^{m}b^{n})({\epsilon_{pq}}^{j}c^{p}d^{q})\\
&= \epsilon^{ijk}(\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n})(\epsilon_{pqj}c^{p}d^{q})\\
&= \delta^{ijk}_{pqj}(\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n})(c^{p}d^{q})\\
&= \delta^{kij}_{pqj}(\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n})(c^{p}d^{q})\\
&= \delta^{ki}_{pq}(\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n})(c^{p}d^{q})\\
&= 2(\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n})(c^{[k}d^{i]})\\
&= (\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n})(c^{k}d^{i}) - (\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n})(c^{i}d^{k})\\
&= (\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n}d^{i})c^{k} - (\epsilon_{mni}a^{m}b^{n}c^{i})d^{k}\\
&= a^{m}(\epsilon_{nim}b^{n}d^{i})c^{k} - a^{m}(\epsilon_{nim}b^{n}c^{i})d^{k}\\
&= (a \cdot (b \times d))c^k - (a \cdot (b \times c))d^k\\
\end{align}$$
Which is the desired identity. So basically it reduces to knowing the properties of generalized Kronecker delta systems and their relation with the Levi-Civita tensors.

In tensor notation all of this is somewhat cumbersome and unintuitive (althougth vector notation is **even more** cumbersome and unintuitive, and I would even say some results just are impossible to arrive to).

I recommend using Penrose's graphical notation for tensors, which is very suited for this kind of calculations. Maybe I could post here the derivation of these results using that notation.

Comment: Thats a great answer. I have not see notation like ${\epsilon_{mn}}^i$ before; would you have a reference that goes into more details about the different types of the permutation pseudo-tensor?

Comment: Hi @TedBlack. Tanks for your comment. The notation $\epsilon_{mn}{}^i$ is just a shorthand that means 
$\epsilon_{mn}{}^i=\epsilon_{mnr}g^{ri}$, where $g^{ri}$ is the metric induced on the dual space. In this answer, the $\epsilon$s are not the pseudotensors but the tensors (of weight $0$, i.e. they have no pseudo-ness). I will try to look for a reference for now. I will try to look for something.

Comment: I now realise it was a silly question! I knew tensors have order and type; do they also have weight? Would you recommend a book that covers tensors as thoroughly as possible?